# CarPlay - In dark mode Apple Maps displayed in light mode

Tags: apple-maps, carplay

Using iOS 13.3.1 ... noticed that in dark mode, Apple Maps are always displayed in bright light mode. I read in external forums that Apple Maps are connected with headlights. But I haven't seen any documentation about it. Is this true ? Is there any way (code) to display Apple Maps in dark mode when mode is set to dark?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have forcefully set Light mode for that specific View controller.